# Creating Winkel-Tripel map of countries with different colors

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, software-recommendations

I need a good quality rasterized world map, Winkel-Tripel projection, in which all countries have different (random?) colors. No borders, text, grid or anything else on the map.

Is GIS the right way to go? I found a lot of map data on [naturalearthdata.com](http://www.naturalearthdata.com).

Can I create this map with QGIS?

Do I need ArcGIS?

I'm completely new to GIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a shapefile (vector) for countries as of 2010 from
[http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1).  It think that it would be easier to change the symbology of a vector file than deal with a raster.  Arcmap will project on the fly and you can set the map to a winkel projection (projected->world or world-sphere->winkel).

[image: A quick world map projected in winkel projection]

Answer (score 0):

There's an svg of this projection on wikipedia. All country codes in main map group and easily editable in illustrator

[image: svg tripel winkel projection]

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Perlshaper_Winkel-Tripel_example1.svg#/media/File:Perlshaper_Winkel-Tripel_example1.svg